# IBufferConstruction create buffer with different geometry types (C# ArcObjects)

Tags: arcobjects, c#, buffer

I am using the following method in C#

```
public void ConstructBuffers (
    IEnumGeometry pInputGeometries,
    double distance,
    IGeometry CollectionpOutputBuffers);
```

to create buffers.

In the method above if I have a `IEnumGeometry` with same types of multiple geometries I can dissolve the overlaps to get a single geometry. But when I have a `IEnumGeometry` with different geometry types (points, lines and polygons) and try to dissolve the overlaps I don't get a single geometry but my output (`CollectionpOutputBuffers`) is the same number of geometries as input. Anyone has any idea what may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want one single buffer object, constructed from all geometries in `pInputGeometries`.

The `ConstructBuffers` result contains one buffer from each geometry, but you want one single merged buffer.

This can be done by

- Set `IBufferConstructionProperties.UnionOverlappingBuffers` to `true`, which will merge eventual overlapping buffers
- Create a multipolygon from the resulting CollectionpOutputBuffers polygons